# "Точь в точь(,) как этот" — нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

"Был у меня пес — точь в точь(,) как этот". В оригинале запятая перед "как" не стояла. Нужна ли она тут и, если нет, то почему?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Во-первых, **точь-в-точь** пишется так, как написал я, во-вторых, запятая не нужна, так как наречие "точь-в-точь" и союз "как" вместе образуют единую союзную конструкцию, следовательно запятая ставится только перед ней. В вашем случае стоит тире, так как автор счёл, что предложение неполное (пропущены какие-то члены предложения), хотя я бы не сказал, что это так.